# Displaying two different types of cells after date

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift, twitter

This is kind of tricky but I will try to explain to the best of my abilities.

I have **3 arrays** named:

- allData
- twitterData
- feedData

***allData***
Contains a struct named feedStruct that has two parameters; type and date (both strings)

***twitterData***
Contains JSON from twitter to display 3 tweets as cells in the TableViewController

***feedData***
Contains JSON from my webpage and displays cells with that information. This JSON is not the same as the twitter JSON - they do not have the same parameters and therefore they are separated into two different arrays.

When the JSON is fetched into twitterData and feedData, they each have a function adding their type ("twitter" or "web") and the date of the tweet/article as a unix stamp into the allData (feedStruct) array. That way I can sort the allData array, so the **cells are displayed newest first** as seen below.

I then have this piece of code in my cellForRow function:

```
let sortedData = allData.sorted{ $0.date! > $1.date! }

    if (sortedData[indexPath.row].type == "twitter") {
    // Displaying twitter cell
    let tweet = tweetData[indexPath.row]

    return twitterCell



} else {

    // Displaying web cell

    let item: LocationModel = feedItems[indexPath.row - tweetData.count] as! LocationModel


    return cell
}
```

The problem however is. At the moment, the three twitter cells are newer than the most recently added article from the web. But when the article is newer than the most recently added tweet, both the *let tweet* and the *let item*'s indexPath.row will be messed up, as take data from two different arrays.

**Example of feed**

- Article (indexPath.row = 0)
- Tweet (indexPath.row = 1)
- Tweet (indexPath.row = 2)
- Tweet (indexPath.row = 3) (there are only 3 datas
  in the array and here it is asking for the number 4 spot)
- Article (indexPath.row = 4) (jumps to article 5 instead of 2, because of the tweets)
- Article (indexPath.row = 5)
- Article (indexPath.row = 6)

Hope it is not too messed up to understand. I do not at all know, if this is the way to go (with three arrays) in order to display the data via date.
Thanks for taking your time to read this!

Comment: Add another class : Meta, with a property type, a property date, and a property content, where content is a article, a tweet or anything you want. You init with an article or a tweet, and compute then the type and the date accordingly. You use only Meta objects in `bigArray`, and it will be correctly sorted. and in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, do `let meta = bigArray[indexPath.row]; let cell; switch meta.type case tweet: cell = tableView.dequeue... as TweetCell, etc.

Answer (score 0):

A pattern that I like to use is to define myself an enum that defines both the type of cell and the data to display. Instead of handling multiple collections, you have an heterogeneous data collection that lets you display your cells as defined per the enum type.

**Example:**

```
class YourViewClass {
    enum CollectionViewItem {
        case Article(data: YourArticleData)
        case Tweet(data: YourTweetData)
    }

    private let tableView = UITableView()

    fileprivate var allData: [CollectionViewItem] = []
    private var tweetData: [YourTweetData]
    private var articleData: [YourArticleData]

    init() {
        super.init(frame: .zero)

        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.register(ArticleCell.self, reuseIdentifier: ArticleCell.reuseIdentifier)
        tableView.register(TweetCell.self, reuseIdentifier: TweetCell.reuseIdentifier)
        addSubview(tableView)
    }

    func configure(tweetData: YourTweetData) {
        self.tweetData = tweetData
        mergeAndSort()
    }

    func configure(articleData: YourArticleData) {
        self.articleData = articleData
        mergeAndSort()
    }

    private func mergeAndSort() {
        allData = tweetData.map({ tweet in return CollectionViewItem.Tweet(data: tweet) }) + articleData.map({ article in return CollectionViewItem.Article(data: article) })
        allData.sort() // You will have to figure out how you sort your elements
    }
}

extension YourViewClass: UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        switch allData[indexPath.row] {
        case .Article(let articleData):
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: ArticleCell.reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! ArticleCell
            cell.configure(data: articleData)
            return cell
        case .Tweet(let tweetData):
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: TweetCell.reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! TweetCell
            cell.configure(data: tweetData)
            return cell
        }
    }

    // Assuming theres only 1 section
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return allData.count
    }
}
```

Comment: The class that is both UITableViewDataSource and UITableViewDelegate should contain this code. Depending on your architecture, it could be in a container view or a view controller.

Comment: How do I use the code in the TableViewController? I assume the above code should be in a swift file for itself?

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, `TableViewController` should already be `TableViewDataSource` and `TableViewDelegate`. Otherwise you would just implement the protocols. You could add the methods to your implementation of `TableViewController`. You just have to pass your list of model items with the configure methods I added in my edit.

Comment: Sorry but I cannot make this work. Problem with almost every line in your code incl. "YourArticleData" and "YourTweetData" :/

Comment: `YourArticleData` is the data model you have defined for your article objects. `YourTweetData` is the data model you have defined for your tweet objects. You can replace them with your classes you have. If you don't have a model object for them, I suggest you make a simple struct/class for that. Same goes for `ArticleCell` and `TweetCell` (you need to implement your specialisation of `UITableViewCell` for each).

Comment: Impossible to create a struct for a twitter json, isn't it?

Comment: You have multiple options for that. Either you do the mapping yourself by fetching the json values with swiftyjson or native json API + dictionnaries. Or you implement the Codable protocol (which will require some knowledge of how to do that mapping).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163819/discussion-between-francis-beauchamp-and-d-finna).